# JXPathContext get list

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Basically, what I am trying to aim is to get the values from a Map that has some values as list.

What I was trying to do is something like:

```
JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(mapVariable);
Object value = context.getValue("*[name()='entryKey']");
```

This always returns the first element from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to use `selectNodes()` method from JXPathContext.

Solution would be:

```
JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(mapVariable);
List<Object> values = context.selectNodes("*[name()='entryKey']");
```